Sufficient number of data to determine whether a model fits the data well
I was wondering if, chosen a proper mathematical model, there is a minimum number of data that allows us to state if the model fits well the data or it doesn't.
I'll explain better my question. Let's suppose that we have a non-linear model with an arbitrary number N of parameters, $y=f(n_1, n_2, n_3, ..., N)$. Let's suppose also that we have an experimental apparatus that allows us to obtain data about $y$ for a certain value of each parameter. For the first experiment we set $n_1$ to be $n_1^*$, $n_2$ to be $n_2^*$ and so on for each of the N parameters. We start the test and we obtain the value $y_1$
$y_1=f(n_1^*, n_2^*, n_3^*, ..., N^*)$
We repeat the test M times varying each time the values of the N parameters and we collect all the data. After doing this, we fit the data with the model.
How can we say if the model fits well the data or it doesn't? Is there a statistical parameter that helps us? And moreover, is there a minimum value of M that allows us to say if the model fits well the data?
Thank you in advance!

You need more observations than parameters. How many more depends on the problem and there are at best rules of thumb. I've often factors of about 10 mentioned, so at least 30 observations for 3 parameters.

Yes, I heard of this factor 10 too. I tought I could find something more "rigorous".

I don't know how you would begin to be more rigorous here, across models with quite different structure and datasets with different properties. 2 distinct points would suffice to determine a straight line, but would not allow any assessment of uncertainty. 4 distinct points might be enough if error was small; 40 or 400 might leave massive uncertainty.
